# The following from address failed, joomla 2.5

Tags: email, smtp, gmail, joomla2.5, chronoforms

I am using chronoforms to set forms on my site. After submission I want to send that information to the administrator of the site by sending mail notifications. But when the client submits the info the following error is displayed:

> The following from address failed admin@admin.com

I have set SMTP settings on my joomla site using gmail SMTP settings as follows:

```
mailer: SMTP
from email: mygmail@gmail.com
sendmailpath: /usr/sbin/sendmail
smtpsecurity: ssl
port: 465
user: mygmail@gmail.com
pass: ***********
host: smtp.gmail.com
```

I have found the Acymailing component and modify to work with SMTP. What else could I do?

Answer (score 0):

Set the From Email address to the address you have in the site SMTP settings, make sure that the To Email address for the admin is a different one as some mail servers - GMail in particular - will drop emails when the From and To addresses are the same.

Comment: thanks i will try as soon as i get home. I will lwt you know.

Comment: hello @GreyHead , i did what you suggested and on chronoforms settings for the email i added the From Email address using the same used on the SMTP settings. Same error is displayed but with the address i set. So instead of having the error as: "..from address failed admin@admin.com" i got: newemailset@email.com. Any other suggestion? Thanks in advanced